# regex remove size like "486X60"

Tags: regex

I need to remove banner sizes from a string,

banner sizes can be 486X60 or 49 X 120

How can I use regex to replace this with blank?

Answer (score 2):

```
s/\d+\s*[Xx]\s*\d+//
```

Comment: don't you mean "\s\d+\s*" instead of "s/\d+\s*"?

Comment: Not really, no.  The information OP provided isn't sufficient to know whether that's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is something like

```
1 or more digits
a space (optional)
X
another space (optional)
1 or more digits
```

The exact syntax depends on what language you're using, but it would look something like

```
s/\d+[ ]?X[ ]?\d+//
```

or, if you want to be sure that the X either has spaces on both sides or none at all, you can separate the two cases:

```
s/(\d+ X \d+)|(\d+X\d+)//
```

This will cover exactly the two example cases you mentioned. If you want to allow any amount of whitespace around the X, or allow the X to be lower case, chaos's solution covers that.

Comment: This is what I ended up with thanks, let me know if you guys spot any thing wrong with it.  

[0-9]+\s*[Xx]\s[0-9]+

Also, here is a tool that I use at this site. http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Thanks guys

Comment: Ok, that's equivalent to chaos's answer except that you're now *requiring* a whitespace character after the X. If you want to make it optional, add a * after the second \s.